# Stop caching in Django

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap, caching, browser

I am using **Django with Bootstrap 4** in project with my own custom css for design.

Every time when I make new design change in css file I have to clear my browser cache and reload the page to view changes or if I rename the custom css file then my design changes are visible.

Is there any way I can disable caching just for development and I can enable while it is in live environment. I am new to this and Django is huge. Please share what is best practice to do this.

Comment: Can you read the document about [Django’s cache framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/cache/)?

Answer (score 2):

Append `?n={{random_number}}` in your template to the css path.

You can write a custom template tag to get a random number like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36744109/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-a-template-django-python/54572073)

Comment: How will this solve the problem. I didn't get the point.

Comment: It will force browser to get the file from server (because it is a new path with a new get param).

You can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9692722/2732913